# How to convert mysqli_fetch_assoc results into json format?

Tags: php, json

i am trying to convert the result of my query into a json format so i can grap it with jquery in another file. I dont get any errors but its not recognised as json.

```
    $patientquery = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE assignedTo='$logID'");

    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($patientquery);

    if($numrows > 0)
    {
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($patientquery))
        {
            $dbloginID = $rows['loginID'];
            $dbname = $rows['name'];


            $result[] = array('patient'=>array('id' => $dbloginID, 'name' => $dbname));


        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result[] = 'No Patients yet';
    }

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: make sure you declare `$result = array();` above your if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this:

```
$patientquery = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE assignedTo='$logID'");

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($patientquery);

$result = array();

if($numrows > 0)
{
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($patientquery))
    {
        $dbloginID = $rows['loginID'];
        $dbname = $rows['name'];

        $result['patient'][] = array('id' => $dbloginID, 'name' => $dbname);
    }
}
else
{
    $result[] = 'No Patients yet';
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But now i have the problem that it only displays one result instead of all patients that are on the database.

Comment: This worked for me:   $result['patient'][] = array('id' => $dbloginID, 'name' => $dbname);

Answer (score 1):

You should declare $result outside while loop like this

```
$result = array();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But now i have the problem that it only displays one result instead of all patients that are on the database.